# Viewport on different displays

Tags: html, css

I used 100vh on my content div inside body tags, but problem is that my background image doesn't look OK when the height of the display is more than 800px , if it's less than 800 then everything is fine and image is 100vh, but if it's more, then a white space appears on the bottom. Here is the css of that div:

```
.content {
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(../img/Background.png) no-repeat center top;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: How does it look with `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: exactly how it should look, there are no white  spaces